# ModuleNotFound cause 502 deploying django with zappa on aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa

**[RESOLVED]**

I've faced ModuleNotFound error when try to deploy django  to aws via zappa.

when i tried to run server locally using below commmand it works well

```
(venv) python manage.py runserver

or

(venv) python manage.py runserver --settings=remoteMedi.settings.prod
```

zappa settings is like

[image]

result `zappa tail` is like

[image]

folder hierachy is like

[image]

installed_app is like

[image]

why i can't get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[RESOLVED]**

The reason is folder hiearchy.

you have to place zappa_settings.json with manage.py on the same directory.

it's like

```
remoteMedi
ㄴ manage.py
   zappa_settings.json
   authenticate
   remoteMedi
   healthcheck
```